# Bicentric quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

I'm trying to prove that a 'tangential' quadrilateral (i.e. one with an in-circle) whose area is given by Brahmagupta's formula for a cyclic quadrilateral is also cyclic (and thus 'bicentric').

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that, stated as a theorem, the Brahmagupta condition has a converse:

A cyclic quadrilateral has the largest area for the lengths of its sides. This means any particular quadrilateral satisfying the condition is unique, and therefore cyclic.

I'm therefore withdrawing my problem.

Comment: That is not actually the converse, though. :)